# jQuery trigger click on anchor tag opening same url in two new tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On clicking a `div` I am trying to trigger an anchor tag and open its URL in a new tab using jQuery. It's working but opening the same URL two times.

I have written some jQuery code to detect the click on a particular div and trigger a click event on its anchor element. When I click the div it causes the jQuery version of the website to open and the HTML anchor tag is also getting clicked directly.

```
<div class="website-open">
  <a class="icon--preview" target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" role="button" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="myimage.php">
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
// Js to open website link 
$('.website-open').click(function(e) {
  window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: You've already set `target="_blank"` on the `a` in order to open it in a new window. The JS is redundant and can be removed. If you're trying to make the whole `div` clickable, set the `a` element to fill all available space in CSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comment.  Yes I want to achieve whole `div` clickable through Jquery. Probably you are right to fix it on html css level. But I am not aware  how to  set the `a` element to fill all available space in CSS

Comment: Wrap the entire div in the anchor tag and then remove the JavaScript.

Comment: @MdEqbalAhmad `a.icon--preview { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }` should make the link fill the div.

Comment: *alternatively* - remove the `target="_blank"` and add `return false` at the end of your click event.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing script to open the url in a new tab, and your anchor tag also gets clicked. that's why it's opening up twice.

Simply change your script to this:

```
$('.website-open').click(function(e) {
  $(this).find('a').click();
});
```